# CMake Xcode using wrong files in Issue Navigator

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake, xcode6

I generate an Xcode project from CMake that builds a static library and test executable.

After the library is built, there is a file copy operation that moves the headers to a central directory (an include folder next to the built library).

This directory is not listed in the header search paths for either project (I have verified this inside the Xcode project and CMakeLists files).

When I am working in the generated Xcode project, the Issue Navigator will open the files in the central directory instead of the files used to build the project.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how I can fix it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate build directory. Create a new directory. Navigate to that in terminal and say :

```
cmake -G Xcode <path_to_source>
```